# How do I get "grunt open" to start the Phonegap Developer Desktop Preview

Tags: cordova, gruntjs

The Preview readme at https://github.com/hermwong/phonegap-gui/blob/master/README.md is extremely terse on how to run the Phonegap Developer Desktop Preview. It requires knowledge of grunt.js, which I am slowing learning for this project.

I now have grunt running on my Mac OS X system and can do a few basic commands within the standard Hello World PhoneGap project folder, but I don't know how to target the Desktop Preview app with grunt. How is that done?

Perhaps I'm not supposed to use Grunt?

My environment:

- Mac OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks on 2010 Mac Mini
- Cordova CLI 4.0.0 (cordova, not phonegap)
- Installed node, npm, grunt, cordova

Comment: The description reads `Initial prototype of creating a GUI for the PhoneGap CLI.` You need to have the PhoneGap CLI installed. PhoneGap and Cordova are not the same.

Comment: Thanks! I'll get that going. So how would I start the program through Grunt?